# How can I pass an object<R: Read> to child function

Tags: rust, struson

I've finally got a use-case that I'm trying to write in Rust - splitting a JSON array into chunks of n records. I'm using the `JsonStreamReader` from https://github.com/Marcono1234/struson as a basis, and struggling a bit with my approach - I'm creating a `JsonStreamReader` object in `fn main()` and passing that to the function which does the actual processing, returning a Vec<serde_json:: map :: Map, serde_json:: map :: Values> (and Box) - there's a bit of recursion going on.

What I'm having a problem with is how to declare the processing function:

```
   Compiling json-split v0.1.0 (/mnt/c/Users/jmcpherson/code/playground/rust/json-split)
error[E0782]: trait objects must include the `dyn` keyword
  --> src/main.rs:33:52
   |
33 | fn process_stream(theReader: &mut JsonStreamReader<Read>) -> Result<Vec<Map<Keys, Values>> , Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
   |                                                    ^^^^
   |
help: add `dyn` keyword before this trait
   |
33 | fn process_stream(theReader: &mut JsonStreamReader<dyn Read>) -> Result<Vec<Map<Keys, Values>> , Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
   |                                                    +++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0782`.
error: could not compile `json-split` (bin "json-split") due to previous error
```

When I followed `rustc`'s suggestions, though, I got this instead:

```
jmcp:~/code/playground/rust/json-split$ cargo build
   Compiling json-split v0.1.0 (/mnt/c/Users/jmcpherson/code/playground/rust/json-split)
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn std::io::Read + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
    --> src/main.rs:33:30
     |
33   | fn process_stream(theReader: &mut JsonStreamReader<dyn Read>) -> Result<Vec<Map<Keys, Values>> , Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
     |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
     |
     = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn std::io::Read + 'static)`
note: required by a bound in `JsonStreamReader`
    --> /home/jmcp/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/struson-0.3.0/src/reader.rs:1752:29
     |
1752 | pub struct JsonStreamReader<R: Read> {
     |                             ^ required by this bound in `JsonStreamReader`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `json-split` (bin "json-split") due to previous error
```

Should I really declare my reader as `static` inside `fn main()`?

Comment: Note: The error message is complaining that `Sized` is not implemented, the `'static` just happens to be there as well and doesn't have anything to do with your error directly.

Comment: @user2407038 that was the info I needed, thankyou. Could you change your comment to an Answer please so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there are some misunderstandings about what `dyn` is and where it can be used. `JsonStreamReader<dyn Read>` is not a sensible type because `JsonStreamReader` stores values of type `R` but no `dyn T` can be used in that context.

You probably want the parameter to be generic, e.g.

```
fn process_stream<R : Read>(theReader: &mut JsonStreamReader<R>) -> ...
```

However `&dyn Read` or `Box<dyn Read>` may also work depending on your needs.